# Why is this code render 0,2,3,0,1,2,3 etc

Tags: reactjs, arrays, loops, react-hooks

```
   const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
   useEffect(()=>{
     if (index === 3){
         setIndex(0)
         console.log(index)
     }else{
       setTimeout(() => setIndex((index) => index + 1), 2000);
       console.log(index)
       
     }
     }, [index]);
```

So my question is why is this code above skips 1 the first time?
The console.log() gives back the following 0 0 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 now here I understand the 0 0 cause I logging it out then the 2 for some reason I don't get it and again 3 0 1 2 is understandable

I want to change the name in the DOM according the index of it in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **developement** mode the `useEffect` [will run twice on mount](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts) because of StrictMode.

So the `setTimeout` will run twice and since you're not providing a [cleanup function](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) it will live on and keep setting the state. Which results in setting the state twice and so going from `0` to `2`.

In **production** StrictMode is disabled and thus will not fire the `useEffect` twice.

Instead you could do something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let timeoutId;
  if (index === 3) {
    setIndex(0);
    console.log(index);
  } else {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setIndex((index) => index + 1), 2000);
    console.log(index);
  }
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}, [index]);
```

However if you're trying to make some sort of counter/interval I recommend using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // set id to use in the cleanup
  const timerId = setInterval(
    () =>
      // use inline check so we have access to the actual index
      setIndex((prevIndex) => {
        if (prevIndex === 3) return 0;
        return prevIndex + 1;
      }),
    2000
  );

  return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, []);
```